# How can I execute code after form close?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code in my project:

```
{
    Lib.Settingsform f = new Lib.Settingsform();
    f.Show();
    LoadSettings();  
    InitializeInterface();
}
```

I want to call above methods after `f.Show()` when the form closes but they run at the same time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should write those in the closing event of the form

Comment: it will do unless you create your form as modal or add something to prevent processing until the form is closed. User `f.ShowDialog()` and use code in your form to close it

Comment: Show some context for that code. Where is it located?

Comment: If you want the code to execute when the form closes then put the code in an event for that.  Currently you have the code on the immediate next line after showing the form.  So... It executes immediately after showing the form.

Comment: if you want to trigger these methods after closing `f` the you have to call these methods in `Closing event` of `f` through `delegates`

Comment: f.FormClosed += new System.EventHandler(LoadSettings());
f.FormClosed += new System.EventHandler(InitializeInterface());              causes error on compile!

Comment: are you trying to do a splashscreen or some kind of processing/wait window ? there are easy ways to do this depending on what you are actually trying to acheive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use ShowDialog()

```
using (Lib.Settingsform f = new Lib.Settingsform())
    f.ShowDialog();

LoadSettings();
InitializeInterface();
```

This will block the thread until the form is closed.